# Using Cypress taking screenshot results in different size in local environment and when running in Jenkins pipline

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm using Cypress and cypress-image-diff-js for visual regression tests.
Running Cypress headless generates screenshots in different sizes than the configured viewport in my cypress.config.ts file.
When running the test in my Jenkins pipeline, again, it generates screenshots in different sizes, failing the tests.

cypress.config.ts

```
{
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: "URL",
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
    supportFile: "./cypress/support/e2e-mock.ts",
    video: true,
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return getCompareSnapshotsPlugin(on, config);
    },
  },
  viewportWidth: 1300,
  viewportHeight: 800,
}
```

cypress-image-diff.config

```
const config = {
  FAILURE_THRESHOLD: 0.02,
  RETRY_OPTIONS: {
    log: true,
    limit: 3, // max number of iterations
    timeout: 20000, // time limit in ms
    delay: 500, // delay before next iteration, ms
  },
  CYPRESS_SCREENSHOT_OPTIONS: {
    capture: "viewport",
  },
};
```

Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks!